# $scope passing has a Delay

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angular-broadcast

I'm building an Angular pop-up system for multiple purposes. The way it works is that I have a directive called `bitPopup` which three variables get passed on to (`type`, `action` and `data`) as shown below:

**index.html**

```
<bit-popup type="popup.type" action="popup.action" data="popup.data"></bit-popup>
```

**popup.js**

```
app.directive('bitPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: html,
    scope: {
      type: '=',
      action: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    [***]
  }
}
```

The popup controller then loads a different directive based on the type:

**popup.html** *(The HTML template shown above)*

```
<div class="pop-up" ng-class="{visible: visible}" ng-switch="type">
  <bit-false-positive-popup ng-switch-when="falsePositive" type="type" action="action" data="data"></bit-false-positive-popup>
</div>
```

**false_positives.js** *(Containing the `bitFalsePositivePopup` directive)*

```
[...]
scope: {
  type: '=',
  action: '=',
  data: '='
}
[...]
```

And then the html template for the `bitFalsePositivePopup` directive displays some properties from `data`.

Now the way I'm triggering a pop-up works like this:

1. From a template inside a directive containing the `bitPopup` directive i'll change `$scope.popup`'s `type`, `action` and `data`.
2. I'll do `$scope.$broadcast('showPopup');`
3. The `bitPopup` directive will react because of `$scope.$on('showPopup', [...]});` and makes the pop-up visible.

Now this really weird thing occurs where it works on the first try (the pop-up opens with the correct `data` information), but after the first try it will display the `data` from the previous try.

Now what's even weirder is that I tried logging the information on the first try and what I found out is that:

- `$scope.popup` at **index.html** just before calling `$scope.$broadcast('showPopup');` displays the right information.
- `$scope.data` at the `bitPopup` directive displays `null`
- `$scope.data` at the `bitFalsePositivePopup` directive displays the right information.

On the second try:

- `$scope.popup` at **index.html** is correct again.
- `$scope.data` at the `bitPopup` directive displays the information from the previous attempt
- The same holds for the `bitFalsePositivePopup` directive.

Another weird thing is that when I use `$scope.$apply()` it does work correctly, only it displays the `$apply already in progress` error. I know I shouldn't use `$scope.$apply()` in this case, because it's all Angular events. But how is it possible that the passed scope is always a step behind?

Am I doing something wrong to begin with?

**EDIT:**

Because of [amahfouz's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34535910/5731727) I decided to post some more code for clarification. I left out some unimportant details for more clear reading.

**index.html**

```
<div class="falsePositives" ng-controller="falsePositives">
  <i class="fa fa-minus color-red" ng-click="triggerPopup('falsePositive', 'delete', {detection: getDetection(row.detection, row.source), source: row.source, triggers: row.triggers, hash: row.hash, date: row.date})"></i>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil" ng-click="triggerPopup('falsePositive', 'edit', {detection: getDetection(row.detection, row.source), source: row.source, triggers: row.triggers, hash: row.hash, date: row.date})"></i>

  <bit-popup type="popup.type" action="popup.action" data="popup.data"></bit-popup>
</div>
```

**index.js**

```
var app = require('ui/modules').get('apps/falsePositives');

app.controller('falsePositives', function ($scope, $http, keyTools, bitbrainTools, stringTools) {
  function init() {
    $scope.getDetection = getDetection;

    $scope.popup = {
      type: null,
      action: null,
      data: null
    };
  }

  function getDetection(hash, source) {
    return {
      'ids': 'BitSensor/HTTP/CSRF',
      'name': 'CSRF Detection',
      'description': 'Cross domain POST, usually CSRF attack',
      'type': [
        'csrf'
      ],
      'severity': 1,
      'certainty': 1,
      'successful': false,
      'input': ['s'],
      'errors': []
    };
  }

  $scope.triggerPopup = function (type, action, data) {
    $scope.popup = {
      type: angular.copy(type),
      action: angular.copy(action),
      data: angular.copy(data)
    };

    test();

    $scope.$broadcast('showPopup');
  };

  function test() {
    console.log('$scope.popup: ', $scope.popup);
  }
}
```

**popup.html**

```
<div class="pop-up-back" ng-click="hidePopup()" ng-class="{visible: visible}"></div>
<div class="pop-up" ng-class="{visible: visible}" ng-switch="type">
  <bit-false-positive-popup ng-switch-when="falsePositive" type="type" action="action" data="data"></bit-false-positive-popup>
</div>
```

**popup.js**

```
var app = require('ui/modules').get('apps/bitsensor/popup');

app.directive('bitPopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: html,
    scope: {
      type: '=',
      action: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope) {
      $scope.visible = false;

      $scope.$on('showPopup', function () {
        console.log('$scope.data: ', $scope.data);
        $scope.visible = true;
      });

      $scope.$on('hidePopup', function () {
        hidePopup();
      });

      function hidePopup() {
        $scope.visible = false;
      }

      $scope.hidePopup = hidePopup;
    }
  };
});
```

**false_positives.js**

```
var app = require('ui/modules').get('apps/bitsensor/falsePositives');

app.directive('bitFalsePositivePopup', function () {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    template: html,
    scope: {
      type: '=',
      action: '=',
      data: '='
    },
    controller: function ($scope, objectTools, bitbrainTools, keyTools) {

      function init() {
        console.log('$scope.data @ fp: ', $scope.data);
      }

      function hidePopup() {
        $scope.data = null;
        $scope.$emit('hidePopup');
      }

      $scope.$on('showPopup', function () {
        init();
      });

      init();

      $scope.hidePopup = hidePopup;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Without the rest of the code I can only guess: You either need to use a promise when displaying the popup or use the $apply service to make the change to the popup visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I added some more code to the original post, maybe that helps to clarify the cause of the problem.

Comment: I looked at the documentation for [Angular's promise](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q), but it feels weird to make the pop-up a asynchronous service. Also as mentioned in the original post, using $apply gives me the `$apply already in progress` error.

Comment: I know, but I had a similar problem with the drop down service and the promise solved it. Anyways, worth a try.

Comment: Using promise sadly didn't do it for me. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Let me take a closer look, but it would help if post a plunk to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

surround your $broadcast event in $timeout like follow:

```
$timeout(function() {
  $broadcast('eventName');
});
```

It will wait for $scope update and then will trigger the event.